# Prove or disprove. Calculations on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove
$[(A \triangle B) - C] ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C) = [A - (B \triangle C)] ∪ [B - (A \triangle C)]$

I can't get any idea how to solve that one. I have changed (A ÷ B) into (A∪B - A∩B) but still I don't see what step should be my next one.

So now I have left side like this:

$(A∪B - A∩B - C) ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)$

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean the [Symbol](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Set_Symbols.htm) "÷" ?

Comment: It's like set A and set B but we exclude common part of A and B.
I can draw it and post an image if you want.

Comment: Or here it is on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: [Symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference): $\triangle$ (\triangle) ?

Comment: Yes it's called symmetric difference. However we have never used triangle symbol to represent it.

Comment: Draw it. It looks like it will become pretty clear. P.S. Mauro is saying use \$\triangle\$ in MathJax i.e. $\triangle$

Comment: @RobertFrost Yeah, drawing will make it easy to prove. However I am supposed to prove it in more 'advanced' way. Ehh…

Comment: Drawing it will show you what's going on so you can understand the problem statement before you start

Comment: @RobertFrost I always try to draw it and see what is going on. I will to give it one more try.

Comment: One approach is to expand both sides out to the power set of $A,B,C$ on an inclusion-exclusion basis, i.e. $A\cap B\cap C,A\cap B\setminus C,B\cap C\setminus A,C\cap A\setminus B,A\cap(B\setminus C),B\cap(C\setminus A),C\cap(A\setminus B),\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a truth table:

$\begin{matrix}
  A & B & C & [(A \triangle B) - C] ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C) & [A - (B \triangle C)] ∪ [B - (A \triangle C)]\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & ? & ?\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & ? & ?\\
  0 & 1 & 0 & ? & ?\\
  0 & 1 & 1  & ? & ?\\
  1 & 0 & 0  & ? & ?\\
  1 & 0 & 1  & ? & ?\\
  1 & 1 & 0  & ? & ?\\
  1 & 1 & 1  & ? & ?\\
\end{matrix}$

If (and only if) the $[(A \triangle B) - C] ∪ (A ∩ B ∩ C)$ column and the $[A - (B \triangle C)] ∪ [B - (A \triangle C)]$ column are identical, then the sets are identical.

You can proceed by building the truth tables of intermediate sets such as $[(A \triangle B) - C]$ and combining them.

Comment: A little back to the past, but if I will show that a statement (not exactly this one) is true for every of these 8 variants, can I then say that Left = Right? Or it is still not enough?

Comment: @JamesSmith Imagine you have two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ and you want to show that they're equal. If you have a third set $A$, you can do it by showing that $S_1 ∩ A = S_2 ∩ A$ AND $S_1 ∩ A^c = S_2 ∩ A^c$. This is the same thing except you have $A$, $B$ and $C$ instead of just $A$, so there are $2^3$ combinations you need to test instead of $2^1$